# Scala - reduceGroups on a KeyValueGroupedDataset with a single value in a group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections

I have a `DataSet[Metric]` and transform it to a `KeyValueGroupedDataset` (grouping by `metricId`) in order to then perform `reduceGroups`.

The problem that I've faced is that when there is just one record with some `metricId`, like `metric3` in the example below, it is returned as-is and the `processTime` field is not getting updated. However when there is more than one record with the same `metricId`, they are getting reduced and the `processTime` field is updated correctly.

I guess that it's happening since reduceGroups needs at least 2 records in a group and otherwise just returns the single record unchanged.

But I can't figure out how to achieve updating the `processTime` field when there is a single record in a group?

```
case class Metric (
metricId: String,
rank: Int,
features: List[Feature]
processTime: Timestamp
)

case class Feature (
featureId: String,
name: String,
value: String
)

val f1 = Feature(1, "f1", "v1")
val f2 = Feature(1, "f2", "v2")
val f3 = Feature(2, "f3", "v3")

val metric1 = Metric("1", 1, List(f1, f2, f3), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-07-01 00:00:00"))
val metric2 = Metric("1", 2, List(f3, f2), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-07-01 00:00:00"))
val metric3 = Metric("2", 1, List(f1, f2), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-07-21 00:00:00"))

val metricsList = List(metric1, metric2, metric3)

val groupedMetrics: KeyValueGroupedDataset[String, Metric] = metricsList.groupByKey(x => x.metricId)

val aggregatedMetrics: Dataset[(String, Metric)] = groupedMetrics.reduceGroups {
  (m1: Metric, m2: Metric) =>
    val theMetric: Metric = if (m2.rank >= m1.rank) {
      m2
    } else {
      m1
    }

   Metric(
      m2.metricId,
      m2.rank,
      m2.features ++ m1.features
      Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()),
    )
}
```

Comment: I would use a `map` after the reduce to update the process time field. Other option, would be to write your own **Aggregator**.

Comment: What's the idea of 'theMetric' variable?